# bypass captive portal(wifi payment direct page) when ping is restricted

Tags: linux, networking

I have been experimenting how to bypass captive portal(e.g. wifis that without password but redirect users to a https payment gateway pages). I know that if they haven't configure the captive portal properly (e.g.only limit browsers requests in such a way that I can ssh to a server or ping to anything website without issues), in which case there is a "IP OVER icmp tunnel" method where one can set up a tunneling to access the internet.

However, I'm just wondering what if pinging any website resulting in timeout or not researchable 
does it mean the configuration allows only https request to the redirect website(payment gateway) only and there is no ways to bypass captive portal (e.g.via tunneling)

with thanks,
I

Comment: Sorry, but it is unclear what you ask. A network "ping" can simply be filtered by a firewall. That is all that means. What do you mean by "captive portal" and by "bypass"? Why don't you simply write what you want to do?

Comment: Hi arkascha, thanks for your response. I have rephrased the question, let me know if there are any issues.

Comment: Ah, so you are looking for a way to be able to use a Wifi offered under commercial terms without having to pay for it.

Comment: I'd say there is no general answer possible for this. Obviously the situation, so network topology, filter setup, routing setup, ... completely depends on the specific setup you find at such a place. There is no general solution, you will have to investigate and try yourself.